# Searching a node of a binary tree in Prolog

Tags: prolog

A beginner in Prolog,working with binary trees for some hours.But as a newcomer in Prolog world,a little bit confused about it's working procedure.
I do some code to form a tree and counting nodes of the tree.When i test,the program outputs just like as..

```
?- constructTree(T),count_nodes(T,N).
T = tree(1, tree(2, tree(3, nil, nil), tree(4, nil, nil)), tree(5, tree(6, nil, nil), tree(7, nil, nil))),
N = 7.
```

Where **T** is the corresponding tree and **N** represents the node number of the tree.

Corresponding code is:

```
constructTree(tree(1,
            tree(2,
                tree(3,nil,nil),
                tree(4,nil,nil)),
            tree(5,
                tree(6,nil,nil),
                tree(7,nil,nil))
        )
    ).
count_nodes(nil,0).
count_nodes(tree(_,L,R),N):-
    count_nodes(L,CL),
    count_nodes(R,CR),
    N is CL+CR+1.
```

How can i implement searching nodes techniques,especially if i want to use **DFS** searching? Consider,i want to find the node 5 using DFS search and count iteration number needs to find that node.
Explanation along with code will be great helpful to understand this new language..:)

Comment: do you learn it by yourself? what are you using?

Comment: What have you tried so far? By the way, your sample data is a min-heap, not a binary search tree.

Comment: See my code above,do you please explain difference between min-heap and binary search tree..@DanielLyons

Answer (score 1):

How count_nodes/2 is implemented? That should be very, very similar to a search procedure. Just add the search argument, and stop visiting (and counting) when when the value gets matched.

Comment: I mentioned my code above,i will try what you have said.As i'm new,so i need some time to habituate with Prolog..:). I have one more question,if it is DFS search that you mentioned,then what will be the case(procedure) in BFS search?

Comment: BFS just swap the order of recursive call WRT DFS. Such simple swap nevertheless has heavy implications on efficiency (fundamentally, it also swap time/space efficiency :)